# Why is .map returning values on console but not in elements defined on React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, gatsby, array.prototype.map

I have an array of objects. I need to inject the key values of each object in a React rendered element (in a Gatsby project). When I check my debugger the correct values are obtained but the elements do not render. What is it that I am missing?

My objects look like this:

```
const obj= [ 
0: {heading: "text, descriptionText: "text"}
1: {heading: "text, descriptionText: "text"}
2: {heading: "text, descriptionText: "text"}
3: {heading: "text, descriptionText: "text"}
4: {heading: "text, descriptionText: "text"}
]
```

the map statement looks like this and each console.log prints accurate data:

```
return ( <div>
        {console.log('slides: ', slides)}
        {slides.map((slide: any, i: number) => {
          <div>
            {console.log('heading: ', slide.heading)}
            {console.log('text: ', slide.descriptionText)}
            <h3 key={i}>
              {slide.heading.toString()}
            </h3>
            <p key={i}>
              {slide.descriptionText}
            </p>
          </div>
        })})
```

Comment: toString() is a function. Invoke it

Comment: Plus, keys should be on top level element. Add a key to the div inside the map method. Also its a bad practice to use index as keys. Use a slide.id if available. (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: toString() was a type error on this question. I do have proper keyvalues on my actual code I just shortened them for this question.

Comment: Could you post a sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a return when you are using curly braces in arrow function. Else you can remove the curly braces after = >

```
        {console.log('slides: ', slides)}
        {slides.map((slide: any, i: number) => {
          return(<div>
            {console.log('heading: ', slide.heading)}
            {console.log('text: ', slide.descriptionText)}
            <h3 key={i}>
              {slide.heading.toString()}
            </h3>
            <p key={i}>
              {slide.descriptionText}
            </p>
          </div>)
        })})
```

Comment: Thank you my lint just did not catch that! It was wrong syntax all along! ARGHH!

Comment: Lint will not catch it, whatever is inside curly braces is the body of the function  and you can decide what to return from function using return keyword